# Link html to another html file

Tags: html

I have 2 HTML files , index.html that have 1 button , and process.html that have function Login() script... when i press the button, it redirect to process.html and process the function Login() automatically ... What must i do ? using a href or what?

index.html

```
<div class="login">
        <div class="fb"><img src="facebook.JPG" style="cursor:pointer;" height="50px" width="250px"/><br></div>
</div>
```

process.html

```
<html>
function Login()
{
//code that process login
}
</html>
```

Comment: This is tagged javascript and PHP, but contains neither. There's also no button in your code at all.

Comment: unless you've instructed Apache to treat `.html` files as PHP, your code won't work. You need to rename `process.html` to `process.php`. Plus, the way you have it now, is really hard to say whether that function is JS or PHP.

Answer (score 2):

In index.html you put onclick="location.href='process.html'" at 'img' tag:

```
<div class="login">
    <div class="fb">
     <img onclick="location.href='process.html'" src="facebook.JPG" style="cursor:pointer;" height="50px" width="250px"/><br>
    </div>
</div>
```

At process.html you put 'login();' function at the end of login code, you may use jquery document.ready function or body onload.:

```
<html>
<script>
function Login()
{
//code that process login
}
Login();
</script>
</html>
```